# How to debug and fix a runtime error like "Unhandled exception at 0x.... in ....exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x...."

Tags: c++

For a project of mine, I am writing a save file reader.
In the latest build I am getting a runtime error `Unhandled exception at 0x00075256 in Final Assessment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCCC.`

How can I go on to identify and correct the source of this error?

I believe the error happens when I create the ifstream object `saveFile()`, but I have been unable to find the exact source.

```
bool Game::load(){
    string data[9];
    ifstream saveFile("save.dat");
    int x = 0;
    if (saveFile.is_open()){
        while (!saveFile.eof()){
            getline(saveFile,data[x]);
            x++;
        }
        saveFile.close();

        string savePlayerName = data[0];
        int saveBaseHealth = stringToInt(data[1]);
        int saveHealth = stringToInt(data[2]);
        int saveKilled = stringToInt(data[3]);
        int saveMoney = stringToInt(data[4]);

        string saveWeaponName = data[5];;
        int saveAttack = stringToInt(data[6]);

        string saveArmorName = data[7];
        int saveDefense = stringToInt(data[8]);

        mainPlayer.setName(savePlayerName);
        mainPlayer.setBaseHealth(saveBaseHealth);
        mainPlayer.setHealth(saveHealth);
        mainPlayer.setEnemiesKilled(saveKilled);
        mainPlayer.setMoney(saveMoney);

        mainWeapon.setName(saveWeaponName);
        mainWeapon.setAttackPower(saveAttack);

        mainArmor.setName(saveArmorName);
        mainArmor.setDefense(saveDefense);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image: Debug]

Comment: BTW, [`while (!saveFile.eof()){` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/560648). Which book told you to write that?

Comment: You "believe" that's when the error happens ... when does it actually happen? What did debugging tell you?

Comment: have you used a debugger yet?

Comment: btw redesign your while loop to `for (int x = 0; x < 9 && std::getline(saveFile, data[x]) ; ++x ) {}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe not the immediate reason of your crash, but here goes:

`while (!saveFile.eof())` is an anti-pattern that's a common source of off-by-one errors. The reason is that it returns `true` only after an attempt is made to read past the end of file. That means you get one iteration too much, one `x++` too much and you go out of bounds in `data[x]`, invoking undefined behaviour.

Sometimes. Unfortunately, you might get away with it and it would appear to work.

Change the loop to

```
while (getline(saveFile, tempString) && x < 9) {
    data[x] = temp;
    ++x;
}
```

and see if it makes a difference.

(The above code doesn't account for input with less than 9 lines, mind you. Also, I'd suggest you use a `std::vector` instead of a C-array.)

Comment: You're right, thanks, I never realized that could cause an error.